# How to extract specified content from PDF

Tags: c#, .net

How can I extract specified content from a PDF file and write it to a new PDF file?

The PDF file contains questions and answers. I want to extract each question and answer combination to a new file. All the questions will start with "*Q".

I need working code written in C#.

Comment: please show some source... what have you tried ? what is not working ? which pdf library are using ? if you don't have a pdf library: would a commercial library be ok ?

Answer (score 1):

There are some tools you can use to read the content of a pdf in C#.

Two that I've used are:

- [Aspose PDF for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx)
- [iTextPDF](http://itextpdf.com/)

And [here](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries) you can find a list of free PDF tools.

Comment: content i want get it as image.i want queation answer combination.

Comment: We can't write the whole program for you :) What is it that you can't get working on your own?

Comment: after converting pdf to bytestream,wherther is it possile to find position of a string&index of that

Comment: You should not convert the pdf to a bytestream and search trough the bytes. You can use a PDF tool like the ones mentioned to open the pdf, let them parse the bytes, and then access it in a more semantic way

Comment: after getting byte array,how can we find the index of particular string.

Comment: @user731060 ask about finding the index of a particular string in a separate question